# Windows Server 2012 Essentials - Safe to delete default accounts?

Tags: windows-server-2012, user-accounts

I'm using Windows Server 2012 Essentials with the trial version. It has a 25 limit and currently I'm a bit over that.

I'm wondering if is safe to delete some of the default users that got automatically added in way back when we setup our last server, some of these are: SBSMonAcct, Discovery Search Mailbox, Host Master, Microsoft Exchange, Microsoft Exchange Approval Assistant, Standard User, Standard User with admin links..

Most of these are marked as "inactive", whatever that means. Basically I think these are never used, but I don't know enough to know if it is safe to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may delete the "inactive" accounts... no the others.
But run a "baremetal" backup first.